# How does AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo's PendingIntent work?

Tags: android, android-pendingintent

I am trying to use `AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo` to set an alarm.

The constructor to this takes the time and a `PendingIntent` which is described in the docs as:

> an intent that can be used to show or edit details of the alarm clock.

and then `setAlarmClock( )` also takes in a pending intent which is described in the docs as:

> Action to perform when the alarm goes off

I understand the use of the `PendingIntent` by `setAlarmClock( )`, however, how is the `PendingIntent` used by `AlarmClockInfo` and how do I use it to edit the details of the alarm clock?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

> however, how is the PendingIntent used by AlarmClockInfo and how do I use it to edit the details of the alarm clock?

Quoting myself from [this book](https://commonsware.com/Android):

> The biggest issue with `setAlarmClock()` is that it is visible to the
>   user:
>
> - The user will see the alarm clock icon in their status bar, as if
>     they had set an alarm with their device's built-in alarm clock app
> - The user will see the time of the alarm when they fully slide open
>     their notification shade

[image: Notification Shade, Showing Upcoming Alarm]

> - Tapping on the alarm time in the notification shade will invoke
>     the `PendingIntent` that you put into the `AlarmClockInfo` object

So, given this code...:

```
  static void scheduleAlarms(Context ctxt) {
    AlarmManager mgr=
      (AlarmManager)ctxt.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent i=new Intent(ctxt, PollReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pi=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ctxt, 0, i, 0);
    Intent i2=new Intent(ctxt, EventDemoActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pi2=PendingIntent.getActivity(ctxt, 0, i2, 0);

    AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo ac=
      new AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo(System.currentTimeMillis()+PERIOD,
        pi2);

    mgr.setAlarmClock(ac, pi);
  }
```

(from [this sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus))

...when the user taps on the time in the notification shade, `EventDemoActivity` will appear. The idea is that you should supply an activity here that allows the user to cancel or reschedule this alarm.

Comment: *The idea is that you should supply an activity here that allows the user to cancel or reschedule this alarm*  Can this not be done by using a `Notification` with two actions - one to dismiss and one to snooze?

Comment: @LittleChild: Sure, if you want to give the user two ways of managing the alarm (`Notification` and the alarm-supplied activity), and two icons in the status bar (one for the `Notification` and one from the system for the alarm).

Comment: @Ankhwatcher: That is an excellent question... and I have no idea. If nothing else, you can cancel the `PendingIntent`, but it would be cleaner to be able to cancel the whole `AlarmClockInfo`, and I do not see how to do that. You might try asking a separate Stack Overflow question on that.

Comment: @CommonsWare oh I deleted the question because it was silly. You can delete alarms set this way just the same as normal you just need to call cancel on a recreated PendingIntent with the same content as "pi" in this example.
I thought you had to do something else because i got my pending intents mixed up when I implemented it.