# setAlarmClock not arriving properly on Moto E3

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-alarms, motorola, motorola-droid

I want to get an exact sampling plan to work. Therefore I've used the
`setAlarmClock (AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo info,  PendingIntent operation)` Method from `AlarmManager`.

[https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setAlarmClock(android.app.AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo, android.app.PendingIntent)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setAlarmClock(android.app.AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo,%20android.app.PendingIntent))

On most devices it works perfectly but on the Motorola Moto E3 there is in 30 % of all cases a delay of max ~4 min.

I've also reproduced it with a random alarm clock app from the playstore (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.urbandroid.sleep).

But the normal alarm clock of android works properly without any delay. Is this a problem of the device or Lenovo/Motorola? Why is the alarm clock of android working? Owns the standard alarm clock different rights?

Comment: Check this out : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36110812/difference-between-setexact-and-setalarmclock

Comment: Thx for the comment, so the standard alarm clock is a "core system component"?