# Difference between setAlarmClock and setExactAndAllowWhileIdle

Tags: android

It is mentioned the following at the link hereafter (Pertaining to Doze mode in API level 23):

- If you need to set alarms that fire while in Doze, use setAndAllowWhileIdle() or setExactAndAllowWhileIdle().
- Alarms set with setAlarmClock() continue to fire normally — the system exits Doze shortly before those alarms fire.

What is the difference between setExactAndAllowWhileIdle and setAlarmClock, in regards to Doze mode?

Is setAlarmClock an exact Alarm?

https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby#testing_doze_and_app_standby

Answer (score -2):

Yes `setAlarmClock` is same as `setExactAndAllowWhileIdle`. From [Android Developers Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setAlarmClock(android.app.AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) about `setAlarmClock`

> Due to the nature of this kind of alarm, similar to
>   setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(int, long, PendingIntent), these alarms will
>   be allowed to trigger even if the system is in a low-power idle
>   (a.k.a. doze) mode.

`setAndAllowWhileIdle` is same as `set` except it will get triggered when device in doze mode. If there are multiple `setAndAllowWhileIdle` alarms set in between a short interval, system might trigger all of them at once instead of triggering them one by one after few seconds/minutes. From documentation:

> Under normal system operation, it will not dispatch these alarms more
>   than about every minute (at which point every such pending alarm is
>   dispatched); when in low-power idle modes this duration may be
>   significantly longer, such as 15 minutes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! If both are the same, why are there 2 different methods?

Comment: Thanks CO, we can read the docs. Your "answer" does not answer the question.

Comment: Have a look here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36110812/difference-between-setexact-and-setalarmclock