# alarm manager - when set alarm show alarm icon in right taskbar

Tags: java, android

I have a simple app where i am setting an alarm. The alarm works fine. However, when the alarm is set there is no alarm icon in the right taskbar to let the user know the alarm is active. Im not sure how to do this.

**Code snippet**

```
 alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
 intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
 pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
 alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time, pendingIntent);
```

What can i do to show an alarm icon in the right taskbar to show the user that the alarm is active. I will need to show/hide this icon depending if the alarm is turned on/off.

Thank you

**EDIT**

I tried this and it still doesnt work.

```
 AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo ac= new 
 AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo(System.currentTimeMillis(),
                            pendingIntent);

if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
      alarmManager.setAlarmClock(ac , pendingIntent);
  } else {
 Intent alarmChanged = new
 Intent("android.intent.action.ALARM_CHANGED");
 context.sendBroadcast(alarmChanged);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `AlarmManager.setAlarmClock (AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo info, PendingIntent operation)` for Lolipop and after.

and `sendBroadcast(Intent intent);` for pre Lolipop

```
 if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        AlarmManager.setAlarmClock(info, mPendingIntent)
    } else {
        setStatusBarIcon(true);
    }

    protected void setStatusBarIcon ( boolean enabled)
    {
        Intent alarmChanged = new
        Intent("android.intent.action.ALARM_CHANGED");
        alarmChanged.putExtra("alarmSet", enabled);
        sendBroadcast(alarmChanged);
    }
```

also see [this](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/android-developers/pUP15UcZi2M/discussion)

Comment: I am unsure what info is? and how to use it

Comment: see this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34699662/how-does-alarmmanager-alarmclockinfos-pendingintent-work

Comment: What is sendBroadcast? because its not resolvable

Comment: nvm i used context and its resolving. Now, i need to figure out how to use info properly