# How To give notifications on Android on specific time in Android Oreo?

Tags: android, notifications, sharedpreferences, settings, alarmmanager

I am looking for a way to create a `preference` in `Settings` to send a notification at a specific time of the day (set by user in settings) in an Android app. I have looked at different threads like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34517520/how-to-give-notifications-on-android-on-specific-time), however this is not working in Android Oreo.

Can someone help me with this or point me to a tutorial?

Comment: Since no one responded...Does the notification really have to be sent at a *specific* time? In many cases no, but if the answer is yes then AlarmManager.setAlarmClock is the only realistic local alternative. Another solution is to use a high priority FCM: Firebase Cloud Message. If delays of up to ~10 minutes can be tolerated then something like AlarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle might be useful. Otherwise see if your app can tolerate using JobScheduler.

Comment: Yes, I want to send a daily notification at the user specified time. Alarm Manager can work in my case, however I am looking for an implementation method. A tutorial that works for Android Oreo, to be exact.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

After looking at different posts and some research on `AlarmManager` implementation, this is what worked for me.

The base for this is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34518115/7077178) post and Schedule repeating Alarms Android [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms).

This is my current implementation:

I have a `SwitchPreference` and a `TimePicker` implementation is `Settings`

SwitchPreference to ask if user wants to enable Repeating Daily Notifications.

TimePicker to set the Notification time.

In `MainActivity`'s `OnCreate` method or wherever you are reading the `SharedPreferences` do this:

```
PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.preferences, false);
SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
Boolean dailyNotify = sharedPref.getBoolean(SettingsActivity.KEY_PREF_DAILY_NOTIFICATION, true);
PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();
ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(this, DeviceBootReceiver.class);
Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, alarmIntent, 0);
AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

// if user enabled daily notifications
if (dailyNotify) {
    //region Enable Daily Notifications
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, sharedPref.getInt("dailyNotificationHour", 7));
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, sharedPref.getInt("dailyNotificationMin", 15));
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 1);
    // if notification time is before selected time, send notification the next day
    if (calendar.before(Calendar.getInstance())) {
        calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    }
    if (manager != null) {
        manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            manager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
        }
    }
    //To enable Boot Receiver class
    pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver,
            PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
            PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
    //endregion
} else { //Disable Daily Notifications
    if (PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, alarmIntent, 0) != null && manager != null) {
        manager.cancel(pendingIntent);
        //Toast.makeText(this,"Notifications were disabled",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver,
            PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
            PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
}
```

Next add `AlarmReceiver` class that implements `BroadcastReceiver` like this:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Objects.requireNonNull(context));
    SharedPreferences.Editor sharedPrefEditor = prefs.edit();

    NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);

    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

    PendingIntent pendingI = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
            notificationIntent, 0);
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("default",
                    "Daily Notification",
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
            channel.setDescription("Daily Notification");
            if (nm != null) {
                nm.createNotificationChannel(channel);
            }
        }
        NotificationCompat.Builder b = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "default");
        b.setAutoCancel(true)
                .setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_ALL)
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_foreground)
                .setTicker("{Time to watch some cool stuff!}")
                .setContentTitle("My Cool App")
                .setContentText("Time to watch some cool stuff!")
                .setContentInfo("INFO")
                .setContentIntent(pendingI);

        if (nm != null) {
            nm.notify(1, b.build());
            Calendar nextNotifyTime = Calendar.getInstance();
            nextNotifyTime.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
            sharedPrefEditor.putLong("nextNotifyTime", nextNotifyTime.getTimeInMillis());
            sharedPrefEditor.apply();
        }
    }
}
```

The system will turn off the `AlarmManager` if Device is powered off or reboots, so restart it again on `BOOT COMPLETE` add this class:

```
public class DeviceBootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (Objects.equals(intent.getAction(), "android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED")) {
        // on device boot complete, reset the alarm
        Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, alarmIntent, 0);

        AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        final SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Objects.requireNonNull(context));

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, sharedPref.getInt("dailyNotificationHour", 7));
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, sharedPref.getInt("dailyNotificationMin", 15));
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 1);

        Calendar newC = new GregorianCalendar();
        newC.setTimeInMillis(sharedPref.getLong("nextNotifyTime", Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()));

        if (calendar.after(newC)) {
            calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR, 1);
        }

        if (manager != null) {
            manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                    AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
        }
    }
}
}
```

And Finally do not forget to add these permissions to `AndroidManidest`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

and register your receivers in `AndroidManifest`

```
<application
    <!--YOUR APPLICATION STUFF-->

    <receiver android:name=".DeviceBootReceiver"
        android:enabled="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver" />
```

The `Notification` should be set by this at a specific time of the day specified by `TimePicker` and if user enabled the `SwitchPreference`.

**UPDATE (Aug-2022): For Android 12 Devices**

To make this work with Android 12 devices, you need to modify the `pendingIntent`'s flags from 0 to `FLAG_IMMUTABLE` like this:

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, alarmIntent, FLAG_IMMUTABLE);
```

Up until Build.VERSION_CODES.R, PendingIntents are assumed to be mutable by default, unless FLAG_IMMUTABLE is set. Starting with Build.VERSION_CODES.S, it will be required to explicitly specify the mutability of PendingIntents on creation with either FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE.
You can find more information on PendingIntent Flags [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent#FLAG_MUTABLE)

Answer (score 3):

There are tons of examples of how to do this on StackOverflow, but unfortunately none of them work anymore because Google changed how the AlarmManager works.

- Android 6: Doze
- Android 7: Aggressive Doze [Disables CPU shortly after screen is turned OFF]
- Android 8: Additional restrictions on background services

The *only* AlarmManager option that allows a developer to wakeup a device at a specific time is AlarmManager.setAlarmClock.

[Using setAlarmClock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34699662/how-does-alarmmanager-alarmclockinfos-pendingintent-work)

In addition to the alarm, you can set an intent that will enable you to launch your app when the alarm is clicked.

The device can also be awoken at a specific time using a high priority FCM, Firebase Cloud Message.

But in summary, there is no other option: 'setExact' and associated methods no longer work as the name advertises.