# Why does my alarm not cancel after setting it with thesame request code

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, alarmmanager

I set my alarm this way:

```
  val broadcastReceiverIntent = Intent(context, AlarmReceiver::class.java)
  broadcastReceiverIntent.putExtra(Constants.ALARM_INTENT_TIME, alarm.time)
  broadcastReceiverIntent.putExtra(Constants.ALARM_INTENT_ID, alarm.id)
  broadcastReceiverIntent.action = System.currentTimeMillis().toString()
  val newPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
        context,
        alarm.id?:0,
        broadcastReceiverIntent,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE or PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
  )
 //schedule alarm
 val alarmClockInfo = AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo(calendar.timeInMillis, null)
 alarmManager.setAlarmClock(alarmClockInfo, newPendingIntent)
```

Then I cancel this way:

```
val broadcastReceiverIntent = Intent(context, AlarmReceiver::class.java)
val newPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
        context,
        alarm.id?:0,
        broadcastReceiverIntent,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE or PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
    )

alarmManager.cancel(newPendingIntent)
```

The alarm still fires off, even when I cancel it.
The request code I used to set the alarm is thesame as the one I am using to cancel it.

What could be the cause?

Comment: the problem with request code . but what did you put as request code by  alarm.id?:0 ?

Comment: The request code for creation is:

val id = Random().nextInt(Integer.MAX_VALUE), which is the alarm id;

So, for cancelling I just cancel using same id

Comment: you can try with static number first .. i think the problem you are facing is for request code .

Comment: Its not the request code, I just tried with a static number.

Comment: if you want to use alarm manager  and want to push notification by broadcaster receiver you must have to send a request code by pending intent  for every alarm .. with out request code you cant access..  so first for test purpose you can try using request code as 1 or 2 then you can set random number for dynamic  purpose then put the number in database  then you can cancel the alarm by reading data from database .  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34699662/how-does-alarmmanager-alarmclockinfos-pendingintent-work

Comment: I did so, the problem was not from the request code.

See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was from:

```
 broadcastReceiverIntent.action = System.currentTimeMillis().toString()
```

when setting that alarm.

It appears that that same action is required to **cancel** the alarm.

Removing that line solved the problem.