# Why do we need to pass PendingIntent to both AlarmClockInfo and setAlarmClock()?

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

To schedule an alarm in Android, we need to pass pending intent to `AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo(triggerTime, pendingIntent)` and `AlarmManager.setAlarmClock(alarmClockInfo, pendingIntent)`.
Why `setAlarmClock` requires pending intent again? Wouldn't it be easier to get it from `alarmClockInfo` which it already takes?

Example of a code:

```kotlin
  private val alarmManager = context.getSystemService(AlarmManager::class.java)
    val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
      context,
      alarm.id, // request code
      Intent(context, AlarmReceiver::class.java),
      PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT or PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
    )
    val alarmClockInfo =
      AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo(
        alarm.timestamp.toEpochSecond() * 1000,
        pendingIntent
      )
    alarmManager.setAlarmClock(
      alarmClockInfo,
      pendingIntent
    )
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34699662/how-does-alarmmanager-alarmclockinfos-pendingintent-work